# Static method mimicking Array.from method not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am trying to solve the exercise "Groups" in Eloquent Javascript (https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html just ctrl+f the word "Groups). To summarize I have to create a class, similar to Set, with four methods: add, delete, has and from. The last one should be static.

This is the solution of the exercise:

```js
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.members = [];
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      this.members.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    this.members = this.members.filter(v => v !== value);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }

  static from(collection) {
    let group = new Group;
    for (let value of collection) {
      group.add(value);
    }
    return group;
  }
}

let group = Group.from([10, 20]);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → true
console.log(group.has(30));
// → false
group.add(10);
group.delete(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
```

My doubt concern the static method and the way the author chose to iterate the iterable. Why if I change the static method like this:

```js
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.members = [];
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      this.members.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    this.members = this.members.filter(v => v !== value);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }

  static from(collection) {
    let group = new Group;
    group = [...collection];
    return group;
  }
}

let group = Group.from([10, 20]);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → true
console.log(group.has(30));
// → false
group.add(10);
group.delete(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
```

on console.log(group.has(10));  there is the error "group.has is not a function" ?

Comment: Because now group is an array (that's the `from` method returns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Group.from()` you spread the `collection`, and then return the array. Since the array is assigned to the `group` variable, you get the "group.has is not a function" error.

An alternative way would be to use the `Group` constructor, like the ES6 `Set`, and then you can spread the `collection` inside the `new Group()` in the `Group.from()` method:

```js
class Group {
  constructor(...args) {
    this.members = args;
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      this.members.push(value);
    }
  }

  delete(value) {
    this.members = this.members.filter(v => v !== value);
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }

  static from(collection) {
    return new Group(...collection);
  }
}

let group = Group.from([10, 20]);
console.log(group.has(10));
// → true
console.log(group.has(30));
// → false
group.add(10);
group.delete(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `group` is not anymore a `Group`. Actually it is an `Array` now.

```
let group = new Group;
// in the line below group is not a Group anymore; it's an Array
group = [...collection];
```

And since the Array class does not have the `has` method, this will throw an error